# Vagrant file is not loading properly

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, eclipse-che

I'm trying to install a Vagrantfile on windows 10 for Samsung ARTIK. However, when I use vagrant, it returns this error:

```
bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

The vagrant file is not corrupt, so that isn't the problem. How do I fix this? I have VirtualBox installed already.

Comment: The vagrant box may be corrupted, which and how did you get the box ?

Comment: I got it from the git repository for eclipse che.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:

Turns out the setup process for ARTIK Eclipse Che has changed.

https://www.eclipse.org/che/getting-started/download/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.